# MySQL How to know which row wasn't match?

Tags: mysql

```
 General table 1
 name      |   A  |    B |      C |      D
 ----------+------+------+--------+--------
 Tom       |    0 |    1 |      1 |      0
 Jerry     |    1 |    1 |      0 |      0
 Daffy     |    1 |    1 |      0 |      0
 Bunny     |    1 |    1 |      0 |      0
 Tweety    |    1 |    1 |      0 |      0

 Table A
 name
 Jerry
 Daffy
 Bunny
 Tweety
```

I have 4 tables A, B, C and D. When a name from table A matches the name in table 1, I set column A = 1 and etc for each column.

I have 8000 names in table A, when I run the query to update table 1 it seems that one name is missing, it returns 7999 row matched. Is there a way to find the missing name between the 2 tables?

```
 UPDATE  table1 t1 
 JOIN    A t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
 SET     t1.A = 1;
```

I tried to find the missing name with the following,

```
 SELECT t2.name
 FROM A t2
 LEFT JOIN table1 t1
 ON t1.name = t2.name
 WHERE t1.name IS NULL;
```

but it returns empty set.

Comment: Err, the one that still has `A = 0`?

Comment: There's a misunderstanding here, I have one more name in table A than in table 1, how can I know which one?

Comment: There's a misunderstanding where? The row with `name = Tom` still has `A = 0`, and is therefore the row that didn't match.

Comment: The problem isn't where I have a 0 value in table 1. Table 1 is meant to compare the 4 tables A, B, C and D. For that, everytime a name from table A is "present" we write the value 1 in table 1 column A. One of the name from Table A has no match in table 1, which shouldn't happen, if table A has 8000 rows it should say 8000 rows matched. Instead it says 7999 rows matched, which led me to think that a name is a missing in table 1, and my question here is how to find that missing name.

Comment: You find the row with the value of `A` that didn't get changed by the update. This is the row that didn't match. In this case, the row where `A` is still `0`, which is the one with `name = Tom.` What's so hard to understand about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join would give you the missing name

```
Select t2.name
From A t2
Left join table1 t1
On t1.name = t2.name
Where t1.name is NULL
```

Comment: Is there one duplicate name in table A.   This query can give you the duplicate name Select name, count ( * ) from A group by name having count(*) >1

Comment: excellent, I haven't thought about that. Will check it out right away. Thanks :)

Comment: Indeed that was a duplicate issue. Thanks!